# How do I use a stored procedure to completely overwrite an existing table?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have an existing table that resides in one database, and each night I want to completely overwrite all contents of this existing table (TO_TABLE), with all data from another database/table (FROM_TABLE).

Currently I am manually dropping the TO_TABLE and re-writing it using this:

```
INTO SDE_SPATIAL.GISADMIN.TO_TABLE
FROM GAVIN..AUTH.FROM_TABLE
```

This works fine, but I would eventually like to convert this into a stored procedure and get this to happen automatically every 24hrs.

Does anyone know how to do the above a bit better and ready for a stored procedure??

UPDATE:
This is the code as it currently stands. I was getting these two errors occur when I run it, the first was"Incorrect Syntax near 'ON'" and the other was "Incorrect Syntax near 'END'". 
I removed the ; characters and run again, this time I was getting no errors, and the procedure was being created successfully.

```
CREATE
PROCEDURE [_ACC_OVERWRITE_PROPERTY_DETAILS]
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON
    TRUNCATE TABLE
        SDE_SPATIAL.GISADMIN._ACC_TEMP
INSERT
INTO
    SDE_SPATIAL.GISADMIN._ACC_TEMP
    (
        Parcel ,
        Assessment ,
        House ,
        Street ,
        St_Type ,
        Title ,
        Area ,
        Area_Units ,
        Suburb
    )
SELECT
    parc.pcl_num ,
    parc.ass_num ,
    STAD.HOU_NUM ,
    stad.str_nme ,
    stad.str_typ ,
    parc.fmt_ttl ,
    aps.property_area ,
    LOWER(aps.AREA_INDICATOR) + '²',
    stad.sbr_nme
FROM
    GAVIN..AUTH.AUPRSTAD stad,
    GAVIN..AUTH.AUSRMAST mast,
    GAVIN..AUTH.AV_PROPERTY_SUMMARY aps,
    GAVIN..AUTH.AUPRPARC parc
WHERE
    PARC.PCL_NUM=STAD.PCL_NUM
AND STAD.STR_NUM=MAST.STR_NUM
AND (
        PARC.PCL_FLG='R'
    OR  PARC.PCL_FLG='P')
AND PARC.PCL_NUM=aps.PARCEL_NUMBER
AND stad.SEQ_NUM = 0
END
```

Comment: "Better" how? Is there something wrong with the way you're doing it?

Comment: Well I am right clicking and dropping the TO_TABLE each time I run it, can I overwrite the TO_TABLE instead?

Comment: You can TRUNCATE or DELETE the table instead of dropping it, but that may or may not be better.

Comment: Yes, and you can also `DROP TABLE` it, you don't have to right-click to delete a table.

Comment: Your procedure looks good, but, of course I can't evaluate whether it is correct because I don't know the schemas of your various databases. You have indicated that you're still getting errors. Please attach the text of the error when you attempt to run the `CREATE PROCEDURE`?

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years ago**) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Benno, if you're still having issues with this store procedure, please feel free to PM me.  View my profile for email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it with a SQL Server stored procedure (sorry, but I don't think you named your particular SQL dialect):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ResetSpatialData]
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  TRUNCATE TABLE SDE_SPATIAL.GISADMIN.TO_TABLE;
  INSERT INTO SDE_SPATIAL.GISADMIN.TO_TABLE
    ([field1], [field2], [field3], [etc], [you get the idea])
    SELECT [field1], [field2], [field3], [etc], [you get the idea]
    FROM GAVIN..AUTH.FROM_TABLE;
END
```

You could then schedule this for regular execution on some time basis by using a SQL Server Agent job.

Note: corrected as per @Nick McDermaid's suggestion.

Comment: that looks like it could be a winner... when I try running that code I get the errors:
Incorrect syntax near 'ON'
There is already an object named 'TO_TABLE'

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?  This is written in SQL Server T-SQL language.  Your question didn't state what specific SQL database system you're using.

Comment: `SELECT INTO ` assumes the table doesn't exist so this won't work

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - you are correct, sir.  Correction has been made.

Comment: Can I make one more suggestion: Please always include column names in the insert and select side (I realise none were provided) also it's a really good idea to include datetime column that contains the data the data was loaded. Really helps with troubleshooting.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - agree.  I'll add.

Comment: We are running Microsoft SQL Server 2012, is that what you mean? Sorry im a bit of a n00b

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean exactly.   The statement "SET NOCOUNT ON;" should work perfectly for you the.  Perhaps you entered it as "SET NO COUNT ON;"?

Comment: Please try the latest version of the procedure.

Comment: OK I have progress... I keep getting errors when running the supplied code, one still mentions SET NOCOUNT ON being a problem, and the other is Incorrect Syntax on END.

I will paste an update in my original comment with my code as it stands (fully fluffed out with the field names etc)